# Pasar parámetro de la Vista al Controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspx

estoy utilizando FormCollection para enviar una gestion y no me recive el dato, sabes de alguna otra forma ?

***VISTA***

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Rarg.Models.PersonaModel>>" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        Pagina Inicio
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%: @Html.DropDownList("codGestion", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",  name="gestion" }) %>
</asp:Content>
```

***CONTROLADOR***

```
public ActionResult EstadisticaNotasAreas(FormCollection data)
{
    int Gestion = Convert.ToInt32(data["gestion"]);
    int gestio = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["gestion"]);
}
```

***ESTOS SON LOS DATOS QUE ENVIO A LA VISTA***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

envio 2017 - 2018 que son llenados en mi **DropDownList**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***como puedo devolver el valor seleccionado al controlador ?***

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint en int Gestion y responde ¿Qué tienes en data? ¿Todo null?

Comment: e añadido mas detalles a la pregunta

Comment: ¿Y los datos que recibes en el controlador?¿Dónde están?

Comment: las traigo de una tabla llamada GestionActiva

Comment: Vamos al chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol que esto se va a extender demasiado

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de **Microsoft**, el helper [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg538075(v=vs.111).aspx)

```
public IHtmlString DropDownList(
    string name,
    string defaultOption,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    Object selectedValue,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

El primer parámetro de `DropDownList` es el nombre del `select`, por lo que asumo que el error debería solucionarse al recibirlo como `codGestion` en lugar de `gestion` en `EstadisticaNotasAreas`

```
int Gestion = Convert.ToInt32(data["codGestion"]);
```

Espero que sea la solución a tu problema, saludos!

Comment: me parece que todo lo que está en la pregunta se refiere a un HttpGet y lo que quiere solucionar está en un HttpPost

Comment: @fredyfx asumí que lo recibía por `POST` , aunque es una posibilidad; lo que plantee es porque no estoy seguro de si el `name` como `htmlAttribute` sobrescribe el parámetro `name` del helper

Comment: por eso mismo dejé un comentario preguntando y sigue sin responder, esperemos a ver qué dice :D gracias por el buen ánimo de responder bro, cuando puedas date una vuelta por sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol se la pasa muy bien con toda la hermandad :D

Comment: acabo de intentarlo, `int Gestion = Convert.ToInt32(data["codGestion"]);` no resulto

Comment: @R.Fernandez el método `EstadisticaNotasAreas` utiliza el verbo `POST` no?

Comment: no, es un método dentro mi controlador

Comment: Para poder recibir un `FormCollection` es necesario que utilices el verbo `POST`, agrega, antes de tu método `[HttpPost]`